# How to spoof individual BLE packets

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm doing a security analysis project on an IoT device that uses an unencrypted BLE connection (with ATT protocol) and I want to spoof an individual BLE packet with the source address of an already connected device.  Is there some tool or API that would allow me to do this easily?  I've already tried gatttool and spooftooph but they seem to be connection based and don't allow you to send out single packets with modified fields (as far as I could tell).

Answer (score 2):

You will need some hardware where you can access the radio peripheral directly. What you basically need to do is to find or write a ble sniffer firmware, with the modification that it at a given moment sends a packet on the connection it is currently listening to. But note that the signal strength must be stronger than the original device's signal so it doesn't interfere.

The only open source project I'm aware of is Ubertooth. You will also be able to do this with an nRF52 but then you need to write your own sniffer firmware since Nordic Semiconductor's is closed source.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on Emils reply yet, < 50 rep:

Nordic Semis [nRF Sniffer v2](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/com.nordic.infocenter.tools/dita/tools/sniffer/sniffer_intro.html?cp=5_4) needs only the nRF52DK and wireshark to work as a general BLE sniffer. At 40$ it's not that expensive. I know for a fact they will release a new dongle soon that will sell for ~10-15 bucks if you can wait a a month or two.